# Can NOK and SEK be used interchangeably in the border regions?

Tags: money, sweden, norway, scandinavia, multi-currency

In the past, when CAD and USD were in parity, places near the border had both coins circulated mixed together, that when I paid with CAD banknote I would very often receive changes with CAD and USD coins mixed together.

Now consider NOK and SEK are in parity. Do both circulate freely mixed near the Norway-Sweden border?

Comment: 98% of Swedes never use cash by now. I won’t be surprised if some places don’t accept *any* cash as of 2021.

Comment: @JonathanReez Even if cash payments are rare in Sweden, your number is way out of proportion. According to numbers from Riksbanken (Sweden's Central Bank) published in 2020, 50% of the Swedes are still at least once a month using cash for payments.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo [looks like only 9%](https://www.riksbank.se/en-gb/payments--cash/payments-in-sweden/payments-in-sweden-2020/1.-the-payment-market-is-being-digitalised/cash-is-losing-ground/credit-cards-are-now-also-more-common-than-cash/) are actively using cash as of this year. If I understand correctly the 50% figure includes money given between friends, not just purchases in shops.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, that is not what the statistic you are linking to is saying. It says that 9% of all purchases in shops are paid cash. It does *not* say that only 9% of the Swedes are regularly using cash. I am actually surprised that the number is that high.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, trade at the Norwegian-Swedish border is mostly a one-way phenomenon. Since prices in Norway are usually higher than in Sweden, people from Norway often go to Sweden for shopping, but not so much, or even rarely the other way around. There are even many shopping malls along the border on the Swedish side, targetting specifically Norwegian customers.

That led to it being common, at least a while ago, that most shops at the Swedish side of the border accepted Norwegian cash, but it was much less common that shops at the Norwegian side of the border accepted Swedish money. Even if the currencies right now are almost valued the same, the Swedish crown has at least for the last 20 years usually been worth more than the Norwegian crown and Swedish shops have always taken the difference in exchange rate into account, usually with an unfavourable exchange rate.

As JonathanReez already commented, cash is rarely used in Sweden anymore and it's the same in Norway. It is still very unusual that shops do not accept cash at all as payment, but I would not anymore expect it to be common, that shops in Sweden accept Norwegian cash.

Comment: Interesting. On Swiss-Italian border it is the contrary: on the most expensive side one accept much more both currencies.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi That is not only restricted to the border region. It is not uncommon, throughout Switzerland, that you can pay with euros in many shops. With a population of over 200 million just in the four neighbouring countries using euros compared to the 8 millions in Switzerland using franc, it is not so odd that Swiss shops are willing to do so.